# JavaScript: get NTLM username?

Tags: javascript, ntlm

Can JavaScript get the NTLM username of a user viewing a webpage?

I'm writing a web app that I want to use as part of an intranet, but I'd like to host it in the cloud (behind an Apache password).

Security isn't a big issue: convenience is. I'd like to pick up my intranet users' NTLM usernames directly from the browser, without asking them to reconfigure their browsers or install any extra software. (Note that I don't need passwords, just usernames.)

Or would this be a giant security hole?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think, this will not work without a web-application in between because if i remember correctly NTLM is sent in a html header which you could access through javascript i think. But you won't get the username because ntlm uses a Challenge-Response method to ensure that the user is trusted. And if this would be possible, everyone could use javascript to fake the username and access your protected data.

Comment: I don't care about anyone faking the username - it's a low-security application and it's behind an Apache password anyway, so only trusted users will access it. Oh well, sigh....

Comment: But why is NTLM then used? Isn't it for authentication users against Active Directory? I think NTLM is a good thing for authenticating users Inside of domains.

Comment: Ah, well maybe I don't need NTLM after all. I just need to get the Windows username, any old way, the easier the better, and I don't mind if people fake it: any ideas?